# Istio host is for dynamically created service "*" after enabling TLS

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubeflow, istio-gateway

I have enabled TLS to the ingress while enabling I have changed hosts from "*" to "mydomain.com" now we have CRD which dynamically creates virtual-service and the host of that service is "*" which should be "mydomain.com".

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you expect Istio to create the VirtualService automatically?

Comment: No, I am using istio as part of Kubeflow in this when I am creating resources Kubeflow is automatically creating virtualservice